# For loop in HTML file, {% for x in xxx %}. Native or framework?

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I was looking at some HTML code and I encountered this syntax that I had not seen before:

```
{% for x in xxx %} \n
<li>{{x.something|e}}</li> \n
{% endfor %}
```

I was wondering if this was native HTML, or if it was some special framework. For the record, I saw it in a Jekyll template for github pages but when I tried searching it up, I couldn't find much clarification.

Comment: Not regular HTML.

Comment: That's Twig http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html.

Comment: Does that mean Jekyll on GitHub supports twig?

Comment: That's basic Jekyll templating syntax. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#accessing-collection-attributes

Comment: @JJJ got it, thanks! Things are more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Liquid, the templating language that Jekyll uses to process templates.

The code you posted is a [for](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-designers#for-loops) loop:

> Liquid allows for loops over collections:
>
> ```
> {% for item in array %}   
> {{ item }} 
> {% endfor %}
> ```

You can check the project doc: [Liquid for Designers](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-designers) and [how Jekyll uses it](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/).